# Xubuntu 18.04 LTS - ugly lines when scrollbar active

Tags: 18.04, xubuntu, themes, gtk

I'm working on my gtk theme and I've realized that ugly lines like "- - - 
- - -" appear at the bottom or up when vertical scrollbar is active and,  at the right or left sides (vertical) when horizontal scrollbar active. Looks like that is to show that there is more of the page from up-down or left-right but I can't figure out how to remove them. The default greybird or the mint xfce also show this but some themes don't, like the macbunto or the Radiance theme. That happens not only with the default text editor but also everywhere the scrollbar is activated (like the whisker menu). I've tried to change the gtk-auto-mnemonics from 1 to 0 but nothing happens, it looks like it has nothing to do with this. Does someone knows whats is going on and how to remove them, please? Thanks for all your help.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Could you please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1071005/edit) your question and add maybe a screenshot of what you are seeing so that we can help you determine what could be causing that.  Thank you!

Comment: Poster has sharp eyes! From a brief poking around, this seems to be a feature of *some* gtk3 themes based on Adwaita. Other gtk3 themes that aren't based on Adwaita don't show the dashed lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an **unofficial** workaround in [Awful dotted lines on borders](https://github.com/shimmerproject/Greybird/issues/150) from 2016. The ostensible purpose of the dashed lines is described in the comments but a developer of Greybird [wrote](https://github.com/shimmerproject/Greybird/issues/150#issuecomment-250299053), also in 2016, "for now this is a "won't fix"."

The person who raised the issue [came up with a fix](https://github.com/shimmerproject/Greybird/issues/150#issuecomment-261585570) and it works even in Xubuntu 18.04 for the Greybird theme. However, what happens in the future is unclear:

> For those who wanted to remove this awful lines, You can remove them editing `gtk-3.0/gtk-contained.css` and writing at the end of file this:
>
> `scrolledwindow undershoot.top, scrolledwindow undershoot.right, scrolledwindow undershoot.bottom, scrolledwindow undershoot.left { background-image: none; }`
>
> Cheers!

Here's an image of the dashed lines on the top in the Whisker Menu:

[image: on top]

And here's an image of the dashed lines at the bottom in the Whisker Menu:

[image: at the bottom]

And this is after the workaround:

[image: not dashed lines]

---

Edit: a preferable way to make the change is to stick the code into `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`. If this file doesn't exist, just create it as a plain text file.

My `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` looks like this:

```
* { -GtkWidget-cursor-aspect-ratio: 0.2; } 

* { caret-color: #00FF00; }

scrolledwindow undershoot.top, scrolledwindow undershoot.right, scrolledwindow undershoot.bottom, scrolledwindow undershoot.left { background-image: none; }
```

Comment: That fixed the 'problem'. I only have a gtk.css file in my theme for now. So I've wrote it at the end of it without issues under this comment: 'Bose fix for anti-ugly-lines obsession:'
I didn't know there are other 'base' themes for xfce besides Adwaita because if I remove the gtk3 folder what I get as default for gtk3 apps is a look like Adwaita. Can you suggest one or two?

Comment: 1) Adwaita is actually no longer a separate theme even though it is listed in `/usr/share/themes`. It is part of GNOME and has been for some time now. In the absence of a valid gtk3 theme in `/usr/share/themes`, gtk3 applications will use Adwaita. One feature of the gtk3 aspect of Adwaita is that it is fully CSS and hence doesn't need a theme engine. 2) Maybe you could ask a new question explaining what you want but please make sure to include (i) details of your operating system (ii) how many desktop environments are present and (iii) which is currently in use.